# Random.randint() is not working after refreshing.

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to write, simple character creation page in python. I want option to reroll stats. The problem is that, after refreshing the page, stats stay the same. Below is my code:

Views.py

```
 from my import Character
 ...
 def create_character():
  characterform = CharacterForm() 
   if request.method == 'GET':
   hero = Character()
   hero.gen_stat()
   return render_template('create_character.html', hero = hero, form = characterform)
```

my.py

```
class Character():
 def __init__(self):
  self.attack  = 0
  self.defense = 0
  self.hp      = 0
  self.ini     = 0


 def gen_stat(self,attack = randint(0,10), defense = randint(0,10), hp = randint(10,20), ini = randint(0,5)):
  self.attack  = attack
  self.defense = defense 
  self.hp      = hp
  self.ini     = ini
```

I'm learning python right now, so propably I'm doing something wrong. The weird thing is that, if I refresh after few minutes, the stats change, so maybe it's related to caching?

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default parameters are evaluated only once (when the function is created).

```
>>> def g():
...     print('g() is called')
...     return 1
... 
>>> def f(a=g()): # g() is called when f is created.
...     pass
... 
g() is called
>>> f() # g() is not called!
>>> f() # g() is not called!
```

Replace `gen_stat` as follow:

```
def gen_stat(self, attack=None, defense=None, hp=None, ini=None):
    self.attack  = randint(0, 10) if attack  is None else attack
    self.defense = randint(0, 10) if defence is None else defense
    self.hp      = randint(0, 10) if hp      is None else hp
    self.ini     = randint(0, 10) if ini     is None else ini
```

BTW, According to [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Avoid extraneous whitespace in the following situations:
>
> ...
>
> - More than one space around an assignment (or other) operator to align it with another.
>
>   **Yes:**
>
>   ```
>   x = 1
>   y = 2
>   long_variable = 3
>   ```
>
>   **No:**
>
>   ```
>   x             = 1
>   y             = 2
>   long_variable = 3
>   ```

Comment: Repetition has lead you to use extraneous whitespace for alignment, consider a helper function `return param if param is not None else randint(0, 10)`.

Comment: I'd use `randint(0, 10) if attack is None else attack` etc. to get rid of the `not` but I wouldn't use a helper function for this.  It wouldn't increase readability and as long as the four lines stay together, the risk of having partial bugfixes (i. e. in just one of them) of this code doubling is limited.

Comment: Maybe like this: `for field in ('attack', 'defense', 'hp', 'ini'):` `original = locals()[field]` `setattr(self, field, randint(0, 10) if original is None else original)`